# What is the Laurent series expansion of $\frac{1}{z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the power series expansion of $\frac{1}{z}$?

The full problem is to find the Laurent series of $$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-i)(z-2)}$$ around $z_0$ = i on $0 < |z-i| < \sqrt5$.

If I expand the function $f(z)$ I find, $$f(z) = \frac{1}{2-i}\cdot\frac{1}{z-2} - \frac{1}{2-i}\cdot\frac{1}{z-i}. $$

I can find the series for the first term: $$\frac{-1}{(i-2)^2} \sum(\frac{-z+1}{i-2})^n.$$

But for the second term I have to find the series for $\frac{1}{z-i}$ which in this case can be written as $\frac{1}{w}$.

Does anyone know how I can find the power series of the second term?

Comment: Taylor expansion>

Comment: Near which point?  Clearly not $z=0$ as the function is not defined there.

Comment: Is $z$ complex?

Comment: How about $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(z-1)^n?$ From http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fz+series

Comment: Yes z is complex, and the expansion for 1/z is around z = 0.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a\ne0$; then
$$
\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{a+(z-a)}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{1+\dfrac{z-a}{a}}
$$
Since
$$
\frac{1}{1+t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nt^n
$$
you should be able to finish.

There is no power series expansion at $0$, but there is a Laurent expansion, which obviously is $1/z$ (all coefficients to $z^n$ are $0$, for $n\ge0$).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I could follow most of it until the laurent expansion. How is it obvious that 1/z is the laurent expansion?

Comment: @anonymous It *is* a Laurent expansion around $0$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, I managed to piece it together. Thanks!